# How to xlim the number of points displayed on ggtsdisplay() to avoid overcrowded ts plots (plotting just enough to notice patterns)?

Tags: r, time-series

For example,

```
library(fpp3)
n = 10^4
y = arima.sim(n=n,list(ar=c(0.15)), innov=rnorm(n))
ggtsdisplay(y)
```

is supposed to just give an AR(1) process, so the actual plot of the time series is not particularly interesting. But if that wasn't known, there would be interest in seeing patterns of seasonality or cycles, for example. However, there are so many points that the display is unreadable:

[image]

In the R base plot package, there is the possibility of specifying `xlim =`. Is there a similar feature for `ggtsdisplay()` without affecting the ACF and PACF plots that I am missing on the documentation?

Alternative a parameter such as:

```
at1 <- seq(min(y), max(y), by=0.05*length(y))
axis.Date(1, at=at1, las=2, cex.axis=0.7)
```

to space out the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the source code: `library(forecast); getAnywhere(ggtsdisplay)`. As you can see th default from `ggtsdisplay` creates plots based on `autoplot` + `ggAcf` + `ggPacf`.

If you are not willing to use `{grid}` as `ggtsdisplay` does to arrange the plots, a quick work-around might be to create your own arrangement with `{ggplot2}` and `{patchwork}`:

```r
library(forecast)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)

n = 10L^4L
set.seed(1)
y = stats::arima.sim(n = n, list(ar = .15), innov = rnorm(n))

p1 = autoplot(y) + 
  geom_point() + labs(x = "", y = "") + xlim(c(0, 100))
#> Scale for x is already present.
#> Adding another scale for x, which will replace the existing scale.
p2 = ggAcf(y) + ggtitle("")
p3 = ggPacf(y) + ggtitle("")
p1 / ( p2 | p3)
#> Warning: Removed 9900 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).
```

[image]

The issued warning is due to `xlim(c(0, 100))`. Is this what you want?

Comment: This works exactly right. I'll come around to close. ty!

Comment: I'm getting the following error (different from yours): `Error in `geom_point()`:
! Problem while setting up geom.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `compute_geom_1()`:
! `geom_point()` requires the following missing aesthetics: y`

Comment: This is what I'm trying to run: `n = 500
y =ts(rnorm(100))
p1 = autoplot(y) + 
  geom_point() + labs(x = "", y = "") + xlim(c(0, 100))
p2 = ggAcf(y, lag.max=50)
p3 = ggPacf(y, lag.max=50) 
p1 / ( p2 | p3)`

Comment: Works on my machine. You may need to restart Rstudio. Don't forget to load `library(forecast); library(ggplot2); library(patchwork)`.